# XMLHttpRequest with constantly changing variable URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have an array that has multiple strings in it. Anywhere from 1 to 10 strings. This array is cycling threw each string every 5 seconds.

```
var completeArray = new Array();
completeArray[0] = new comArray('http://domain.com','/sports/','photo','1','http://domain.com');
completeArray[1] = new comArray('10461632','/sports/','video','0','');
completeArray[2] = new comArray('10459620','http://domain.com','video','0','');
completeArray[3] = new comArray('10459542','/sports/m-footbl/recaps/092312aah.html','video','0','');
completeArray[4] = new comArray('http://domain.com','/sports/','photo','0','');
```

Then I have a XMLHttpRequest that takes the variable completeArray as the url. I want it to initiate a new request every time it comes to a string with numbers in the first node of the string such as '10461632',.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: completeArray,
    dataType: "xml", 
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('item').each(function(){
        });
    }
});
```

I have no idea how to go about this and any help or direction to get on the right path would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is comArray? I think you are mistakenly naming it comArray instead of Array. I dont see it defined anywhere. I assumed this and renamed it.

I also made a fiddle that just logs the url into the console so that you can see how it works. I still dont think this is going to accomplish what you need because the URLs are coming out mis-formatted, probably due to the way you created each completeArray node.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dy9kM/12/

```
var completeArray = new Array();
completeArray[0] = new Array('http://domain.com', '/sports/', 'photo', '1', 'http://domain.com');
completeArray[1] = new Array('10461632', '/sports/', 'video', '0', '');
completeArray[2] = new Array('10459620', 'http://domain.com', 'video', '0', '');
completeArray[3] = new Array('10459542', '/sports/m-footbl/recaps/092312aah.html', 'video', '0', '');
completeArray[4] = new Array('http://domain.com', '/sports/', 'photo', '0', '');

$(function() {
 $.each(completeArray, function(index, value) {
    if (value[0].match(/\d/)) {
        length = value.length;
        array = value.slice(1, length);
        url = array.join('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).find('item').each(function() {});
            }
        });
    }
 });
});​
```

Comment: I may not have been complete in explaining what I was having a problem with and needed done. Sorry.